# Narrow the scope of custom Sonar rules in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm trying to code my own Sonar rules but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set a scope for those rules.

Let's say I have a `Foo` superclass and I want to check the constructors and some methods on every child class:

```
public class SubFoo extends Foo {

  private boolean ok;
  private boolean evaluate;
  private Whatever thing;

  /** Compliant: constructor with id argument. */
  public SubFoo(Long id) {
    super(id);
  }

  /** Not compliant: no id */
  public SubFoo(Whathever thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
  }

  /** Compliant: annotated boolean accessor starts with 'is'. */
  @MyAnnotation
  public boolean isOk() {
    return ok;
  }

  /** Not compliant: annotated boolean accessor doesn't start with 'is'. */
  @MyAnnotation
  public boolean hasOk() {
    return ok;
  }

  /** Compliant: not annotated boolean accessor. */
  public boolean canEvaluate() {
    return evaluate;
  }
}
```

- Are `Kind.CONSTRUCTOR` and `Kind.METHOD` adequate as nodes to visit for those rules?
- what is the best way to limit the scope of those rules?

I was thinking of a base class doing a type check in `visitNode` but I'd like to know if there is another recommended way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe share some snippets of code with what is compliant and what is not ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't get notified of your comment. I edited my answer.